# Django form with ModelChoiceField is always invalid

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Below is the relevant part of my template. I'm trying to send the selected field from a dropdown to my form.

```
<form action="character_chat" method="post">
    <select id="character_name">
        {% for character in characters %}
        <option name={{character}}>{{character}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
```

Relevant code from the view:

```
def character_chat(request):
    class CharacterForm(forms.Form):
        character_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Character.objects.all())

    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = CharacterForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            print("Valid form!")
            print(form.cleaned_data['character_name'])
```

I never see the print statements, so it seems the form always ends up invalid. Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use `{{ form.character_name }}` in your template. There's not need to create an html select element because Django gives you this for free. Furthermore, Django actually uses the `name` HTML attribute, not `id`. Also, if you wanted to do it like this without using `form` from your context, your `<option>` tags would look more like this:

```
<option value={{character.id}}>{{character}}</option>
```

Check out the documentation for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

**Update due to comments:**

You need to put the form inside the context for the template before you can use it. Here is a really applicable example taken from [the Django form docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-view):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Notice how if the request method is GET, they render the request with the template, and place `form` inside of the context dictionary? This is what you need to do too:

```
def character_chat(request):
    class CharacterForm(forms.Form):
        character_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Character.objects.all())

    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = CharacterForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            print("Valid form!")
            print(form.cleaned_data['character_name'])
            # now you should redirect
    else: # GET request method
        form = CharacterForm()
        return render(request, 'NAME OF YOUR TEMPLATE HERE', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I removed the select element and I tried putting in the following, copying from the documentation, but then I see no dropdown field. `<div class="fieldWrapper">{{ form.character_name }}</div>` Is this incorrect?

Comment: can you show the full code for your character_chat view? Did you put form inside the context?

Comment: That is the full code for character_chat view, aside from imports. I don't think I've done anything with contexts.

Comment: @user2424607 I've updated my answer to reflect what you should do.